# assign javascript array property declaratively

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, declarative

I'm making a complex tree-like array/object in javascript to create similar pages (with different profiles) dynamically. Because of it's static nature, it's company policy to keep this array in the main constants file (of course, as a declarative constant). So my question is, how can I assign a declarative property in a javascript array? I know I can do the following:

```
var a=[9,6,0,4];
a.title='profile 1';
```

but the problem is those are instructions, and the constant file is one big object, so I can't use that. I know I could use a normal object, but I really want number indexing, dynamic length, push/pop methods, etc. I also know there are substitutes for each like using a number as a property name, Object.keys(a).length, etc., but it would make my life a whole lot easier if it were simply an array. Basically, I need this created in one instruction:

```
Array[2]
>0: Object
>1: Object
>length: 2
>title: "profile1"
>__proto__: Array[0]
```

EDIT:
Because of the confusion, I will try to clear up why I specifically need it to be a single instruction. As I mentioned, the constants file is one big object, with no instructions but it's own declaration, so it has to be a property.

```
CONSTANTS={
    const1: 'something',
    const2: 'something',
    const3: 'something',
    ...
    const60: 'something',
    myArray: [
        [{},{},{},{}],//here the title property would go directly on the array
        [{},{},{},{}],//same
        [{},{},{},{}],//etc.
        ...
    ]
};
```

Comment: There is no way to do what you want in a `var` initializer. Why not make `a` be an object that has the array as one of its properties?

Comment: I have no clue what you expect the output/otcome to be.

Comment: Because it's a dynamic array of arrays, and each array has different certain properties (like title, meta, hidden, etc.). Sorry for not specifying that what I put as an example is not the actual structure. As I said in the beginning, the real object has the complexity of a tree.

Comment: Note that putting string-named properties on an array is perfectly fine for *most* purposes, it can cause some unexpected behaviors. Specifically, were you to decide to serialize the array to JSON for (say) transmission or local storage, the string-named properties would be lost.

Comment: I've actually run into that before, however, since it acts as a guide for the creation of an interface, it's never necessary to serialize, or store in any way.

Comment: If you want `push`/`pop` methods, it's no longer a *constant*?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var a = Object.assign([1, 2, 3, 4], {title: 'profile 1'});
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more native (like assignment ':' or '=') but it does the trick! If someone could come up with a solution without the use of methods (even built in ones) it would be great (for optimization), but for now, this is my accepted answer.

Comment: You could use a temp variable and the comma operator. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: Check my edit, I can't edit anything outside of 'CONSTANTS'